# Changing aria-label based on the binding of css style

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, wai-aria

I have a checkbox that i have an aria-label for but i am not sure of how to change this aria-label text to reflect whether the checkbox is checked or not for the user. Is it possible to control the aria-label text in the same function for rendering the css?

Function for checking and unchecking box:

```
checkbox = ko.pureComputed(function () {
     var checked = checked(),
         uncheck = uncheck(),
         checkedIcon = 'icon_check',
         uncheckedIcon = 'no_check',

                if (checked) {
                    //Can i add in here what the aria-label text should be?
                    return checkedIcon;
                }

                if (uncheck) {
                    return uncheckedIcon;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have you looked at getAttribute and setAttribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if you would like to change the attribute based on check-box value.
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:Mycheckbox,attr:{'aria-label':MyAriaLabel}" >
```

VM:

```
 $(function () {
  var MainViewModel = function () {
     var self = this;
     self.MyAriaLabel = ko.observable('aria-lebel');
     self.Mycheckbox = ko.observable();

     self.Mycheckbox.subscribe(function(newVal){
       self.MyAriaLabel(newVal?'Something' : 'Something else');
     })
  }
  ko.applyBindings(new MainViewModel());
})
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5129/

Answer (score 1):

You could, but it sounds like you're making this more complex than it has to be. Rather than manually setting an aria-label, you can use the native API of the `checkbox` input type. If your html is an actual checkbox input, like:

```
<input id="check1" name="field-name" type="checkbox">
```

then when it's checked off, it should automatically get the "checked" attribute, which screenreaders should be able to pick up on. If that fails, you can use `aria-checked` to supplement it.

```
  var isChecked = element.getAttribute('checked')
  element.setAttribute('aria-checked', isChecked)
```

If you're not using normal `input type="checkbox"` markup for whatever reason, you can add `role="checkbox"` to your markup to help the browser treat it as such.

Bonus: you can even use the native check behavior to handle your css, in some cases, via something like this:

```
[type="checkbox"] { background-image: url('uncheckedIcon.png'); }
[type="checkbox"]:checked { background-image: url('checkedIcon.png'); }
```